# Yacdf, it is posible to retrieve all the filtered data from the table?

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

I want to know if it is possible to retrieve all the filtered data from the table in yacdf, even  the data that is not shown.
I want to export all the filtered data to an excel
 thank you in advance

Comment: its should be done with datatables export api , see docs https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: thank you very much it worked a lot